# Xcode Path to Shared Library in OS X

Tags: swift, xcode, shared-libraries, xcode7, dylib

Im attempting to link to a shared object (.so) and the only place i can get the app to find it is when the file is placed in the same folder as the app bundle itself.

I've changed the "Runpath search path" under linking in Build Settings in the to the usual googled recommendations @exacutable_path/Frameworks and @exacutable_path/../Frameworks is there too and variants of those. I have the library file copying to the app bundle shown in Finder as Contents->Frameworks.

the error I am getting in the console is:

dyld: Library not loaded: libtest.so

Reason: image not found

the library is being accessed by a Framework which is being used by the app

I am using swift and I set up a module.map file if that may be throwing things off. Am I missing a path entry to add to or is there at least a way to log the searched paths to the console at runtime to trouble shoot this? Why does if work if I add the shared library in the same directory as the app bundle?

thanks

it will also run if i place it in usr/local/lib but I'd like to get it found in the bundle if thats possible